# SEDE help page still thinks MSO is the network meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, mso-mse-split

On the SEDE [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) page some of it is referring to Meta Stack Overflow instead of Meta Stack Exchange. In the :

1. [Magic Columns](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) section it says: `... to tag pages on the target site, like the data-explorer tag on Meta Stack Overflow.`, it should be `Meta Stack Exchange`.
2. [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) section it says: `... or to provide feedback, please ask on Meta Stack Overflow!`, again it should be `Meta Stack Exchange`

I know it is just text changes, but thought it should mentioned.

Comment: This is probably something minor compared to all the other things that need to be fixed on SEDE.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how I managed to update the link targets without noticing the text was wrong too, but now [that's fixed as well](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/48) pending a pull and redeploy. Thanks!

Comment: Hehe no problem, I also noticed that the last update of data on SEDE happened last Sunday morning at about 3am UTC and the help page says it is updated on a Monday at 3am UTC. Is that the time it updates now or was it just a once off thing?

Comment: Hm, not sure about that. If the window has indeed moved I'll make sure that text gets updated appropriately.

Comment: Just built out, thanks Tim!

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY Hah, whoops. I've fixed that now too, thanks. :)